# WordPress filter post content with PHP before editing it in Gutenberg

Tags: block-editor

How to filter post content with PHP before it shows up in Gutenberg editor? I've read the following answers but didn't find what I need:

Answer in [Filter post before *editing*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91705/filter-post-before-editing) suggests using the_editor_content filter HOOK which is wrong because what that hook does is to filter the default editor contact.

Answer in [Filter post_content before loading in Gutenberg editor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/367128/filter-post-content-before-loading-in-gutenberg-editor) is a JS based solution.

I also tried HOOK content_edit_pre but it doesn't seem to work in Gutenberg.

I've searched https://developer.wordpress.com and didn't manage to find anything related.